# Search two consecutive words and combine them in python

Tags: python

I have list of lists as follows.

```
mycookbook= [["i", "love", "tim", "tam", "and", "ice", "cream"], ["cooking", 
"fresh", "vegetables", "is", "easy"], ["fresh", "vegetables", "are", "good", 
"for", "health"]]
```

I also have a list as follows.

```
mylist = ["tim tam", "ice cream", "fresh vegetables"]
```

Now, I want to find the consecutive words in `mylist` and combine them  to update `mycookbook`.

I am currently doing it as follows.

```
for sentence in mycookbook:
    for sub in sentence:
        if sub is (mylist[0].split(" ")[0]):
```

But I am not sure how to detect the next word as there is no command `next()`. Please help me.

Comment: what do you mean by nearby?

Comment: `sub is ...` is almost certainly wrong. `is` is an identity test, not a value equality test, so it would only ever work by coincidence in implementation dependent ways. Replace `is` with `==` (about the only common use for `is`/`is not` is comparing with `None` which is a singleton).

Comment: Why is your desired output?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I want to update `mycookbook`

Comment: @yklsga updated the question

Comment: For the record, there is indeed a function named `next()`.  But it's not useful here.  You can step through the elements of mylist just the same way you stepped through the elements of `mycookbook` and `sentence`: with a `for ... in ...` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for sentence in mycookbook:
    i = 0
    while i < len(sentence) - 2:
        for m in mylist:

            words = m.split(' ')
            if sentence[i] == words[0]:
                for j in range(1, len(words)):
                    if sentence[i + 1] != words[j]:
                        break

                    sentence[i] += ' ' + words[j]
                    sentence.pop(i + 1)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer :) How can we change this answer if I have more than two words in `mylist`. e.g., `mylist = ["tim tam", "chocolate ice cream", "fresh vegetables and fruits"]` and `mycookbook= [["i", "love", "tim", "tam", "and", "chocolate", "ice", "cream"], ["cooking", "fresh", "vegetables", "is", "easy"], ["fresh", "vegetables" "and", "fruits", "are", "good", "for", "health"]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate through the indices, looking ahead as much as possible each time. So, something like this:

```
new_sentence = []
index = 0
while index < len(sentence):
    for word in mylist:
        wordlist = word.split()
        if sentence[index:][:len(wordlist)] == wordlist: # This will take the first `len(wordlist)` elements and see if it's a match
            new_sentence.append(word)
            index += len(wordlist)
            break
    else:
        new_sentence.append(sentence[index])
        index += 1
```

You can try it here: [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBT4QwEIXv/RUveBCi2Wi8EfkB3r0R4iIMYbJtIbQR99fjFBYWEufUTt@8r/P6q287@zZNjqwnWxEyRB/Q3Q/Bs4EvDUpbg@WlGqg00cn1mn2cKHPV7Lzo8@imjJ4R3YWFUpbGr51xXii2Nf3K8UWNLWvCcn@HJhuvyiRVkGq6AWM3CNtiYS39UKF/o4fj9qf1nRusbvmMSIs8DYx1MCmQZZtNigd8tuwwstayyUWWbwkND4I4H@bOIE1GvN2ciyMKMPaPcocpfdVunwi1T@BU9j3ZevZKDqolhacMB9RB8i2ZXuYOaUf3JP4DHFcvdrGsnFel@oGtj/fjyTT9AQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each sentence in your original `mycookbook`. Then, for each sentence, start with the pointer pointing at the first word.

- Case 1: If `sentence[i] + ' ' + sentence[i+1]` is not in `mylist`, we just add `sentence[i]` to the new sentence.
- Case 2: If `sentence[i] + ' ' + sentence[i+1]` is in `mylist`, then add this as one word to new sentence, and move pointer forward 2 steps.

Example below.

```
mycookbook= [["i", "love", "tim", "tam", "and", "ice", "cream"], ["cooking",
"fresh", "vegetables", "is", "easy"], ["fresh", "vegetables", "are", "good",
"for", "health"]]

mylist = ["tim tam", "ice cream", "fresh vegetables"]

mycookbook_new = []
for sentence in mycookbook:
    i = 0
    sentence_new = []
    while i < len(sentence):
        if (i == len(sentence)-1 or sentence[i] + ' ' + sentence[i+1] not in mylist):
            sentence_new.append(sentence[i]) # unchanged
            i += 1
        else:
            sentence_new.append(sentence[i] + ' ' + sentence[i+1])
            i += 2
    mycookbook_new.append(sentence_new)

print(mycookbook_new)
'''
[
  ['i', 'love', 'tim tam', 'and', 'ice cream'], 
  ['cooking', 'fresh vegetables', 'is', 'easy'], 
  ['fresh vegetables', 'are', 'good', 'for', 'health']
]
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mycookbook= [["i", "love", "tim", "tam", "and", "ice", "cream"], ["cooking",
"fresh", "vegetables", "is", "easy"], ["fresh", "vegetables", "are", "good",
"for", "health"]]


mylist = ["tim tam", "ice cream", "fresh vegetables"]

result_cookbook = []
for cb in mycookbook:
    cook_book = []
    need_continue = False
    for index, word in enumerate(cb):
        if need_continue:
            need_continue = False
            continue 
        if index < len(cb) - 1:
            # can combine with next word
            combine_word = "{} {}".format(cb[index], cb[index+1])
            if combine_word in mylist:
                cook_book.append(combine_word)
                need_continue = True
            else:
                cook_book.append(word)
        else:
            cook_book.append(word)
    result_cookbook.append(cook_book)
print result_cookbook
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the pairs of each word with the next work using `zip`.  If a word pair is in `mylist`, append it as a single sting and skip the next iteration.

```
out = []
for sentence in mycookbook:
    new_sentence = []
    skip = False
    for pairs in zip(sentence, sentence[1:]+['']):
        if skip:
            skip = False
            continue
        if ' '.join(pairs) in mylist:
            new_sentence.append(' '.join(pairs))
            skip = True
        else:
            new_sentence.append(pairs[0])
    out.append(new_sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

More readable version split into smaller functions.

#### Note

1. The solution does not use any indices at all (numbers).
2. Does not use any stdlib function like `itertools.zip` or `range`
3. Does not mutate any object. All objects are immutable. i.e no use of `pop`, `append` `+=`
4. Can be easily modified to read from some input file and print to another file
5. If modified to read & write to file, will use minimum memory as all contents are not stored in list. i.e works lazily.

---

#### Code

```
def as_pairs(iterable):
    """
    yields two items at a time from iterable
    """
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        current_item = next(iterator)
        while True:
            next_item = next(iterator)
            yield current_item, next_item
            current_item = next_item
    except StopIteration:
        return


def merge_pairs(pair_words, word_list):
    """
    If the pair words are part of the word_list, merges them to one
    """
    pair_map = { tuple(pair_word.split(" ")) : pair_word for pair_word in pair_words }
    for pair in as_pairs(word_list):
        if pair in pair_map:
            yield pair_map.get(pair)
        else:
            first, second = pair
            yield first

def main():
    mycookbook= [
            ["i", "love", "tim", "tam", "and", "ice", "cream"], 
            ["cooking", "fresh", "vegetables", "is", "easy"], 
            ["fresh", "vegetables", "are", "good", "for", "health"]
            ]

    mylist = ["tim tam", "ice cream", "fresh vegetables"]
    return [ list(merge_pairs(mylist, sentence)) for sentence in mycookbook ]

print(main())
```

#### Output:

> [['i', 'love', 'tim tam', 'tam', 'and', 'ice cream'], ['cooking',
>   'fresh vegetables', 'vegetables', 'is'], ['fresh vegetables',
>   'vegetables', 'are', 'good', 'for']]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. If you care about performance mylist should be indexed in some fashion so that the match function can do better than sequential lookup.

Bonus: the entries in mylist can have any number of words, not just two, notice added "good for health".

```
mycookbook= [["i", "love", "tim", "tam", "and", "ice", "cream"], ["cooking",
"fresh", "vegetables", "is", "easy"], ["fresh", "vegetables", "are", "good",
"for", "health"]]

mylist = ["tim tam", "ice cream", "fresh vegetables", "good for health"]

def transform(x):
    def match(i):
        for e in mylist:
            el = e.split()
            if x[i:i+len(el)] == el:
                return e, len(el)
        return x[i], 1
    i = 0
    while i < len(x):
        e, l = match(i)
        yield e
        i += l
answer = [list(transform(x)) for x in mycookbook]
print(answer)
'''
[['i', 'love', 'tim tam', 'and', 'ice cream'],
 ['cooking', 'fresh vegetables', 'is', 'easy'],
 ['fresh vegetables', 'are', 'good for health']]
'''
```