# Combine multiple consecutive words in python

Tags: python

I have list of lists as follows.

```
mycookbook= [["i", "love", "tim", "tam", "and", "chocolate", "ice", "cream"], ["cooking", 
"fresh", "vegetables", "is", "easy"], ["fresh", "vegetables", "and", "fruits", "are", "good", 
"for", "health"]]
```

I also have a list as follows.

```
mylist = ["tim tam", "chocolate ice cream", "fresh vegetables and fruits"]
```

Now, I want to find the consecutive words in `mylist` and combine them as follows to update `mycookbook`.

```
mycookbook = [["i", "love", "tim tam" "and", "chocolate ice cream"], ["cooking", "fresh vegetables", 
"is", "easy"],["fresh vegetables and fruits", "are", "good", "for", "health"]]
```

I am currently using two words as follows.

```
for sentence in mycookbook:
    i = 0
    while i < len(sentence) - 1:
        if sentence[i] + ' ' + sentence[i + 1] in mylist:
            sentence[i] += ' ' + sentence[i + 1]
            sentence.pop(i + 1)
        i += 1
print(mycookbook)
```

Comment: The problem is poorly constrained.  What should be the output for `mycookbook = [['a', 'b', 'c']]` and `mylist = ['a b', 'b c']`?

Comment: @wim `mylist` does not have word phrases like that :)

Comment: @Volka knowing the output of wim's question will help us help you in solving your problem.

Comment: Why did you combine `fresh vegetables`? It's not in `mylist`, only `fresh vegetables and fruits` is.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067841/8870849) to [your question about combining pairs of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066357). It handles substitutions of any length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need nested loops, one for the starting index of a phrase, the next for the ending index. You can then use a list slice to get all the words in between.

```
for sentence in mycookbook:
    i = 0
    while i < len(sentence):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(sentence)+1):
            phrase = ' '.join(sentence[i:j])
            if phrase in mylist:
                sentence[i:j] = [phrase]
                break
        i += 1
```

We can't use `for i in range(len(sentence))` because the length of `sentence` changes whenever we replace a slice with the phrase.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/vQMlmp)

Answer (score 0):

First answer is more efficient, There i tried with itertool approach:

```
mycookbook= [["i", "love", "tim", "tam", "and", "chocolate", "ice", "cream"], ["cooking",
"fresh", "vegetables", "is", "easy"], ["fresh", "vegetables", "and", "fruits", "are", "good",
"for", "health"]]
mylist = ["tim tam", "chocolate ice cream", "fresh vegetables and fruits"]


import itertools

split_list=[i.split() for i in mylist]

for item in split_list:
    for element in mycookbook:
        for iterindex in itertools.product(enumerate(element),repeat=len(item)):
            combination=list(zip(*iterindex))
            match=combination[0]
            if " ".join(combination[1])==" ".join(item):
                for index in match:
                    element[index]=" ".join(item)
replace_list=[]
for item in mycookbook:
    new=[]
    for item1 in item:
        if item1 not in new:
            new.append(item1)
    replace_list.append(new)

print(replace_list)
```

output:

```
[['i', 'love', 'tim tam', 'and', 'chocolate ice cream'], ['cooking', 'fresh', 'vegetables', 'is', 'easy'], ['fresh vegetables and fruits', 'are', 'good', 'for', 'health']]
```